# For which $n$ are there $11\text{,}660$ derangements fixing the first five elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, derangements

This is a practice question for derangements. The text I have only has half a page on derangements and that doesn't help me solve this question.

For positive integers $1,2,3,\ldots,(n-1),n$ there are $11\text{,}660$ derangements where $1,2,\ldots,5$ appear in the first five positions. What is the value of $n$?

Comment: Start by finding the number of derangements of the $5$ integers $1,2,3,4,5$. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to have a list of the number $D_k$ of derangements for the first few $k$. The Wikipedia article has [such a list.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

The number of derangements of $1,2,3,\dots,n$ in which the numbers $1$ through $5$ appear among the first five numbers (though of course not in that order!) is the number of derangements of the first $5$ numbers times the number of derangements of the remaining $n-5$ numbers.

There are $44$ derangements of a set of $5$ numbers. So the number of derangements of the remaining $n-5$ numbers  is $\frac{11660}{44}$. This is $265$. But $265$ is $D_k$ for $k=6$. So $n-5=6$, and therefore  $n=11$.

Comment: You are welcome.